# Randomly renaming the same upload profile picture in php?

Tags: php

I have made image uploading script in `php` that upload image successfully but now I want to rename randomly if user uploaded same profile picture again I have **rand(1,100000)** for that but it gives me error.

**My script is here :**

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
 $_FILES['file']['name']=rand(1,100000).$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 600000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
 
 if (is_file($target_file))
{
echo "Successful<BR/>";
echo "File Name :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$target_file\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
}
}
?>
```

And I got the following error :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a change in this function like this.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $target_file = $target_dir .rand(1,100000). basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
}
```

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(88627upload/14316802_10155315964098146_6539510858801534289_n.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\upload\index2.php on line 40                  this occur

Comment: Which oprationg system are you using ? @RebeccaJoanna

Comment: windows 8.1  target directory right and when i upload new pic it upload corectly

Comment: so what is the problem now?

Comment: please `echo $target_file;`  and tell me what is outupt, i want to know why numbers are adding `88627upload` before upload

Comment: done thank you dear can you recommend me any book or site for improving PHP concept

Comment: read this sites.
http://php.net/manual/en/
http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

change

```html
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
 $_FILES['file']['name']=rand(1,100000).$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

to

```html
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
 $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']=rand(1,100000).$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: it gives following error now File is an image - image/jpeg.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code from :

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
 $_FILES['file']['name']=rand(1,100000).$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

to

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . rand(1,100000) . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code for

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
 $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']=rand(1,100000).$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: already done thank you i tried this but it gives error "File is an image - image/jpeg.Sorry, your file was not uploaded. –"